# cant install packages because of older chromium build

Tags: chromium, packages

i'm trying to install a package using the terminal specifically

```
sudo apt-get install sysbench
```

but i get the following error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 chromium-browser-l10n : Depends: chromium-browser (>= 65.0.3325.181-0+rpt4) but 56.0.2924.84-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1011 is to be installed
 rpi-chromium-mods : Depends: chromium-browser (>= 65) but 56.0.2924.84-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1011 is to be installed
 sysbench : Depends: libmariadbclient18 (>= 5.5.36) but it is not going to be installed
```

I have an older version of chromium because I need widevine. Is it possible to install packages without upgrading chromium to 65?

Comment: What OS + version do you run? On Standard RPF Raspbian Stretch I get Chromium 65 installed without problems. It looks to me that your apt sources are interfering. Add all the apt sources to your question (/etc/apt/sources.list and all list files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d)

Comment: try using ```aptitude``` or ```synaptic``` they're both better at resolving those package co-requisites and pre-requisites. You may need to install those with ```apt install synaptic aptitude```

Comment: I don't know much about widevine, can't it be made to work with chromium 65 as well? If not, then do you need chromium-browser-l10n and rpi-chromium-mods? If not, remove them, since they are what is blocking your sysbench install. Also how did you get those two installed without chromium 65?

Comment: Hi thanks for replying @Dougie i am unable to install any packages so i cant use aptitude or synaptic because i cant install them.

Comment: @T.M. widevine sadly only works on 56 and not newer versions so i had to downgrade in order to use it, i am not sure how to remove chromium-browser-l10n and rpi-chromium-mods, and would removing them cause any problems with my current chromium build?

Comment: @Dirk im on the lastest version of raspbian stretch i had chromium 65 and had to downgrade for widevine support
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi

Comment: @johnsmith in that case you're probably best off starting with a fresh new SDCard and a copy of Raspbian 2018-11-13.

Comment: @Dougie i have already tried that but after downgrading chromium i am unable to install packages as i keep getting the same error

Comment: Why are you downgrading? It goes against the force of the Universe.

Comment: @Dougie like ive mentioned above widevine is only supported on the chromium 56

Comment: So the problem is not chromium but widevine Don't use it or complain to the widevine creator/ maintainer of that program.

Comment: To go against the verse is possible.  must make some nicely contained, portable-ish packages that can be run from anywhere and do not depend on anything external...

Answer (score 1):

If that's what you really want, then

```
sudo apt-get remove chromium-browser-l10n rpi-chromium-mods scratch2
```

will remove the two broken packages. And should allow you to install other packages that don't depend on chromium. Oddly you'll lose scratch2 also since that depends on rpi-chromium-mods.

I feel like there has to be a better way to have a different version of chromium, but [pinning is a good way to break a lot of things too](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences).

Comment: i cant remove them as i get this error
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 scratch2 : Depends: rpi-chromium-mods but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
apt --fix-broken install' forces me to install the newer chromium build which i dont want.

Comment: If you don’t need scratch2 then try adding that to the list of packages to remove. Short version is running different versions of software isn’t very easy.

Comment: @john-smith glad it worked. If you click on answered it helps to close things out of SE I think.

Answer (score 0):

It appears some of the packages you have downloaded have become corrupt.

To fix this, run

```
$ sudo apt clean
```

to delete the package cache, then

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

again so it will download fresh copies.